# Enviar datos a jInternalFrame con un boton desde otro JinternalFrame, sin que este se pierda su visibilidad. JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

mi problema radica en que cuando lo quiero volver a utilizar la misma funcion (presionar el boton para cambiar etiqueta por otro valor de la tabla), la primera ventana se queda sin funcionalidad!. Cuando se hace la primera vez me lo hace perfecto, pero al querer hacer de nuevo es como si fuera que no sirviera nada del formulario. No capta ninguno de los campos de texto ni tampoco los valores de la tabla. Ya hice la prueba con debuguear el codigo. Mi codigo es sencillo es solo capturar un valor de la segunda fila del jtable y de ahi que le guarde en un jlabel. Como dije la primera lo hace perfecto pero despues se queda sin funcionalidad el primer jinternalframe. Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? O las instancias se lo declaran de otra forma? o simplemente falta algo? Aqui va el Codigo:

```
import Controlador.control_Productos;
import Controlador.control_existencias;
import Modelo.Productos;
import com.mxrck.autocompleter.TextAutoCompleter;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public final class vGestion_Productos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    control_existencias conexis = new control_existencias();
    control_Productos producto = new control_Productos();
    Productos p = new Productos();
    private TextAutoCompleter ac;
    String id, fecha, nombre;
    Timestamp fechaseleccionada;
    DefaultTableModel datos;
    public vGestion_Productos() {
        initComponents();
        AutoCompletarCategoriaProducto();
        Mostrar();
        jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta seguro que desea modificar?", "confirmar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        int fila = jTable1.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                        fecha = jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString();
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        try {
                            fechaseleccionada = new java.sql.Timestamp(df.parse(fecha).getTime());
                        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(vLista_Compras.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        id = jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();
                        jTextField1.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
                        jTextField2.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
                        jTextField3.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
                        jDateChooser1.setDate(fechaseleccionada);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void AutoCompletarCategoriaProducto() {
        ac = new TextAutoCompleter(jTextField1);
        Object[] dato = conexis.combox("categoriasproductos", "descripcion");
        for (Object row : dato) {
            ac.addItem(row.toString());
        }
    }

    public void Mostrar() {
        String[] columnas = {"IDPROD", "IDCATEGORIAPRODUCTO", "DESCRIPCION", "PRECIO VENTA", "FECHA REGISTRO"};
        Object[][] dato = producto.MostrarDatos();
        datos = new DefaultTableModel(dato, columnas);
        jTable1.setModel(datos);
        ocultar_columnas();
    }

    public void ocultar_columnas() {
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
    }

    public void LimpiarSeleccion(){
        jTable1.clearSelection();
        jTable1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPopupMenu1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDateChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 =  new javax.swing.JTable(){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                return false; //Disallow the editing of any cell
            }
        };
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPopupMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setAutoscrolls(true);
        setComponentPopupMenu(jPopupMenu1);
        try {
            setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        setVisible(true);

        jLabel1.setText("Categoria");

        jLabel2.setText("Nombre");

        jLabel3.setText("Precio Venta");

        jLabel4.setText("Fecha Registro");

        jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jTable1.setComponentPopupMenu(jPopupMenu1);
        jTable1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("Agregar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Modificar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Eliminar");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Abrir Receta");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 183, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(93, 93, 93)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(123, 123, 123)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 115, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(142, 142, 142)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(129, 129, 129))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 326, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        p.setDescripcion(jTextField2.getText());
        p.setPrecioventa(Float.parseFloat(jTextField3.getText()));

        if (!jTextField2.getText().trim().equals("") && !jTextField3.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            if (producto.InsertarProductos(p)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nuevo Producto agregado");
                Mostrar();
            }
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        p.setDescripcion(jTextField2.getText());
        p.setPrecioventa(Float.parseFloat(jTextField3.getText()));
        p.setIdproducto(Integer.parseInt(id));

        if (!jTextField2.getText().trim().equals("") && !jTextField3.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            if (producto.EditarProductos(p)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificacion Completa");
                Mostrar();
            }
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int seleccionado=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        if (seleccionado == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar una fila");
        } else {
            int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta seguro de Eliminar?", "confirmar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (i == 0) {
                p.setIdproducto(Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(seleccionado, 0)));
                if (producto.EliminarProductos(p)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Eliminado");
                    datos.removeRow(seleccionado + 1);
                    Mostrar();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

// A partir de abajo comienza el problema.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        int seleccionado= jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        if(seleccionado == -1){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar una fila");       
        }else{
            vGestion_Recetas receta = new vGestion_Recetas();
            if(receta.isShowing()==false){
                vMenuPrincipal.jDesktopPane1.add(receta);
                receta.toFront();
                receta.setVisible(true);
                vGestion_Recetas.jLabel2.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccionado, 2).toString());
            }else{
                vGestion_Recetas.jLabel2.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(seleccionado, 2).toString());
            }              
        }
        LimpiarSeleccion();
}
```

Desde ya Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

Bueno encontre la solución a esto. Resulta ser que al segundo jinternalframe (que se abre con el boton), hay que agregarle en su constructor el primer jinternalframe con su correspondiente jdesktoppane añadido del mismo. Parece ser que pierde el componente dentro del contenedor cuando se abre otra ventana sobre la misma ventana.

```
public void habilitar(){
        vGestion_Productos producto = new vGestion_Productos();
        vMenuPrincipal.jDesktopPane1.add(producto); 
        producto.toFront();
        producto.setVisible(true);
}
```

En mi caso hice un metodo que no retorna nada y lo implemento en el constructor del jinternalframe que fue llamado.